# Is this the right way to implement google recpatcha v3?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

**I've added the snippet inside the  tag:**

```js
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=EXAMPLE123456789-_987654321'></script>
```

**After that, I added this javascript callback inside each form on the site:** (grecaptcha above the submit button).

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" target="_blank" action="https://website.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/1234567890" class="infusion-form" id="inf_form_1234567890" method="POST">
    <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="1234567890" />
    <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="First Last.com&#a;Web Form submitted&#a;HOME PAGE&#a;First / Last" />
    <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1.00.00.1" />
    <div>
        <div>
                                <p class ="white">Register Now</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
<div class="user-fields">
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_FirstName_home">First Name *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" placeholder="First Name *" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_Email_home">Email *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" placeholder="Email *" type="text" required />
    </div>
</div>
    <div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
<script>
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
grecaptcha.execute('EXAMPLE123456789-_987654321', {action: 'homepage'})
.then(function(token) {
// Verify the token on the server.
});
});
</script>
    <div class="infusion-submit">
        <button class="infusion-btn" type="submit">Submit!</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://website.infusionsoft.com/app/webTracking/getTrackingCode"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://website.infusionsoft.com/app/timezone/timezoneInputJs?xid=12345678900987654321"></script>
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Why, is it not working properly?

Comment: @charlietfl Maybe? The thing is that I can't tell if it's working or not. The website that I'm using it on doesn't have enough traffic for me to see results in Google, so I'm not sure if it's working or not. I don't get any errors when testing the forms. Does it matter where that script is placed? Does it need to be above the submit button? I just want to confirm that it's setup correctly as I'm currently adding it onto many page forms.

Comment: Are you verifying on server side?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto No, how do I do that?

Comment: What's your backend language?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto It's a WordPress website, self hosted